# Disable buttons, edit texts

Tags: android, android-edittext, progressdialog, android-button, android-progressbar

[image]In my application i am using a custom `ProgressBar`. I have used an image along with  `ProgressDialog` to give effect of shaded `background`. Problem is all `Button`'s and `Edittext`'s are still `clickable` provided image layer is above on it. My image `opacity` is set to 40%. I have set image not `clickable` and also not enable. But nothing stopping my `Button`'s , `Edittext` fields from being clickable.

Like share button is still clickable however an image layer is on it.

Comment: please share some image of view

Comment: @sukhbir I have added image

Comment: please add your layout code

Comment: @sukhbir layout code is too big

Comment: @sukhbir I want to disable three buttons of share, info, favourite by putting an image view above it but with  reduced opacity.

Comment: for that i need to check what you are doing inside  xml layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177178/discussion-between-sukhbir-and-mohammad-aamir).

Answer (score 1):

You can set clickable=true for your images. So it will intercept click event and won't pass to any other buttons that are under this view

Answer (score 0):

You make the buttons not clickable with this code :

Java:

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

XML :

```
 android:enabled="false"
```

And also you can make them disappear with this code :

Java:

```
 yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

XML :

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: I don't want to do that. As there is a lot of such instance in my application in a lot of applications. That's why i am using a image view for disabling them but this is not happening mainly due to opacity of image

Comment: @MohammadAamir You can customize  a shape with 40% opacity and then set the background of that imageView to that shape, this way the imageView's opacity is 100%

Comment: this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set 
`parent.setEnabled(false)`   
to their parent,  whether it's a `toolbar` or a `layout`   
and when the task is finished restore it back to   
`parent.setEnabled(true)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I have put an image above all widgets like buttons, edit text fields and setZ(float value) to that image higher in code. i.e. imageView.setZ(1000). Thus any thing below image is visible but not clickable.